# Is it possible to implement notification grouping/bundling using FCM in ionic?

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending notifications to users with FCM (firebase cloud messaging) using firebase functions.

If a notificatoin sent while there is already old notification in the device I want to group those notifications like [SetGroup](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/group) does.

Is it possible?